# How can I call method of form1 in form2 without create new instance of form1

Tags: c#

I have 2 forms. in form 1, I have a treeview. in one method, I get list of nodes that checked.

```
private void CreateListOfCheckedNodes()
        {
            TreeNodeCollection nodes = TreeData.Nodes;
            Int32 EffectedNodes = GetCheckedNodesCount(nodes);
            if (EffectedNodes > 0)
            {
              ;//my code
            }
        }

        public int GetCheckedNodesCount(TreeNodeCollection nodes)
        {
            int CheckedNodesCount = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < nodes.Count; i++)
            {
                TreeNode node = nodes[i];
                if (node.Checked)
                {
                    TreeFieldSet Item = new TreeFieldSet { TreeId = Int32.Parse(node.Tag.ToString()), Title = node.Text };
                    MyProject.Tree.TreeCheckedNodes.TreeList.Add(Item);
                    CheckedNodesCount++;
                }

                if (node.Nodes.Count > 0)
                    CheckedNodesCount += GetCheckedNodesCount(node.Nodes);
            }
            return CheckedNodesCount;
        }
```

How can I calling method `CreateListOfCheckedNodes` in Form 2 without new of Form1 ?
With this calling :

```
Tree.TreeSubjects Ts = new Tree.TreeSubjects();
Ts.CreateListOfCheckedNodes();//if CreateListOfCheckedNodes public
```

I get error !

Please Help !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move the code into a new class that can be accessed by both forms.

You can  make the method static if it doesn't use any  member variables (a quick glance at the code seems to suggest that this is the case).

```
static class TreeNodeCollectionHelper
{
    public static int GetCheckedNodesCount(TreeNodeCollection nodes)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

You could also consider making it an [extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) of the TreeNodeCollection class, but this should be done with caution as it may surprise your colleagues.

Comment: How to access to controls of form1 in form2 ?

Comment: @a_ahmadi: Why do you need that? Your method doesn't access any controls apart from the one that is passed as a parameter.

Comment: I create new class(thank's from your help), but I use treeview control in form 1. in form 1 I use TreeNodeCollectionHelper.CreateListOfCheckedNodes(TreeData); that TreeData is name of TreeView Control of form1. How can I access to control TreeView of form 1 in form2 to calling in same?

Comment: @a_ahmadi: Well you could add a pubblic property to your form which returns a reference to the control.... But frankly, it seems like a bad idea to access the internals of one form from another. It would be better to define a clear interface for each form and only access data via that well defined interface. Use the same principles that you would use when defining an interface between any two classes that need to communicate or share data.

Comment: I have a few forms in one form(Docking Form). I want in form 2 get list of treeview checked nodes of form1 and use from that. form1 have a lot of controls with big data from database, when create new instance of it, I can't access to data of controls(in form 1 when called in form2)

Comment: @a_ahmadi: Well as I said you could make a public property on your form to get direct access to the control you need, but as I mentioned before it's probably better for you to define a clear interface between your classes and only access data through those well defined interfaces (i.e. pass only data, not references to controls, between forms). But I don't see how this relates to the question you originally asked.

Comment: I define a public property (TreeView type) with name TrDt. but when calling method with new property in form 2,then run, get error in my class that TrDt(TreeView object) is null !!!

Answer (score 1):

I am not completely sure I understood your question but if you are asking how to call a method without having to make a instance of the class then make the method static.